# Creating a key for a JSON file to be searchable

Tags: python, json

I am trying to create a key for a simple JSON file that I can use to lookup the value such as quantity but I don't know what code will allow a lookup from multiple options.

The file is

```
[{"_id": {
"$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000001"},
"product_name": "sildenafil citrate",
"supplier": "Wisozk Inc", "quantity": 261,
"unit_cost": "$10.47"}, 
{"_id": {"$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000002" }, 
"product_name": "Mountain Juniperus ashei",
"supplier": "Keebler-Hilpert",
"quantity": 292,
"unit_cost": "$8.74"}, 
{ "_id": {
"$oid": "5968dd23fc13ae04d9000003" },
"product_name": "Dextromathorphan HBr",
"supplier": "Schmitt-Weissnat",
"quantity": 211,
"unit_cost": "$20.53"}]
```

I have been trying

```
import json
products = open('C:*my computer location here*products.json')
readable_json = json.loads(products)
for i in readable_json:
print i['_id']
```

But am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-88-f380edbf6f26>", line 3, in <module>
readable_json = json.loads(products)

File "C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\Users\computer\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Any research? Any trial? Show it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)** expects a string, use **[`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)**:

```
readable_json = json.load(products)
```